# Preventing aggregation along dimensions' attributes

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

Say I have this schema (sorry for the slightly convoluted example):

```
CREATE TABLE Sales
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Shop NVARCHAR(MAX),
    ShopLocationLeft NVARCHAR(MAX),
    ShopLocationRight NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Amount DECIMAL
)

INSERT INTO Sales VALUES
(1, 'Shop #1', 'New', 'York', 10000),
(2, 'Shop #2', 'New', 'Delhi', 1000),
(3, 'Shop #3', 'North', 'York', 5000)
```

Then I create a cube with a `Shop` **dimension** with 3 **attributes**:

- `Name` (column `Shop`)
- `Location Left` (column `ShopLocationLeft`)
- `Location Right` (column `ShopLocationRight`)

I can explore the cube along this dimension:

```
SELECT
    [Amount] ON COLUMNS,
    [Shop].[Name].Children ON ROWS
FROM
    [Sales]
```

To get:

```
        Amount
Shop #1 10000
Shop #2 1000
Shop #3 5000
```

So far so good.

But using other **attributes** like `Location Left`:

```
SELECT
    [Amount] ON COLUMNS,
    [Shop].[Location Left].Children ON ROWS
FROM
    [Sales]
```

We get:

```
      Amount
New   11000
North 5000
```

So the cube is allowing exploration and aggregation 1 level deeper than the dimension, along the attributes, making them some kind of ***sub-dimensions***.

Which in this case has no business meaning.

I was expecting that, like an SQL `SELECT`, this would display the `Location Left` column instead:

```
        Amount
New     10000
New     1000
North   5000
```

Because for me this dimension has 3 points:

- `('Shop #1', 'New', 'York')`
- `('Shop #2', 'New', 'Delhi')`
- `('Shop #3', 'North', 'York')`

Which should be considered atomic entities that can't be broken down further.

I understand that this behavior can be useful (e.g. for first and last name) but in this case it does not make any sense.

Or if I had defined an **n-levels hierarchy** for an attribute (e.g. country -> city -> location) it would be logical too as I would have explicitly asked for a deeper exploration and aggregation.

How to prevent this behavior when it would lead to non relevant results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an attribute `Location Left` in your `Shop` dimension you can choose ID as the `Key` column and `Location Left` as the `Name` column of this attribute (in the `Dimension structure` tab - right click on the `Location Left` attribute and select properties, then you will look for `KeyColumn` and `NameColumn` properties). If you do this ,you will see 'New' being displayed multiple times in the results.

If you have an attribute say `Location Left` and choose the same `Location Left` both as the `Key` column and as the `Name` column, you will see only one entry per `Location Left` Name.

Comment: Thanks, indeed but, following your idea, in this case I'd need to have a composite name colum: `Shop` would be the key and `ShopLocationLeft + ' ' + ShopLocationRight` the name. Not sure it can be done at the SSAS level. Otherwise creating a dedicated view at the DB level might be a solution...

Comment: And combining that with a way to prevent exploration along the `ShopLocationLeft` and `ShopLocationRight` attributes.

Comment: I think you should create a dedicated view for this purpose as it will be an easiest solution, and you could add something like "Full location" column to your view to be data source for Full location attribute. You can also hide ShopLocationLeft and ShopLocation Right attributes to prevent exploration. But the point was that if you choose appropriate key column (it could be Shop, but also it could be ID from the Shop table), you can get "repeating" or non-repeating effect, which, I think, was your question in the first place? And you can set this in your dimension's definition in SSAS.

Comment: My answer actually has nothing to do with changing table structure or creating a view. Hope you understood that.

Comment: Yes I think I've understood your answer; but ID can't be used as the key for shops as it identifies a sale, not a shop, and many sales can be made in a single shop. I should have made it clearer by adding a fourth record with `ID = 4` and one of the other shops. Anyway +1 for your efforts and pointers. :)

Comment: Oh, I see, in that case it would be the best that you have separate dimension table e.g Shop table, that has FK in you fact table (Sales). In that way you will avoid any ambiguity and also you will have more of a Star schema - database structure consisting of the fact and dimension tables. Take a look here https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/star-schema-olap-cube/

Comment: A star schema is indeed cleaner, but I wanted to keep this sample as basic as possible. Moreover I don't think it would solve my issue as I'm pretty sure the `ShopLocationLeft` and `ShopLocationRight` will remain usable on their own. But again I wish I'm wrong. :)

Comment: OK using a Named Query is the easy way to create the full `Shop Location` (no need for a view), then  adding it as a dimension attribute instead of the two others. Then we can explore along `Shop Location` which makes sense. Please update your answer with these elements as it is close to your idea of using a view, and I'll accept it. :)